# search by one column without index or two one of them has index

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, database, search

I want to know which case is faster based on your experience

A table having more than 10 million records is queried on basis of two case:

- `search1` on a single `product_id` column
- `search2` by two columns `shop_name` (which is indexed) and `product_id`

so it will be like this

```
search1 =    select * from table where product_id = 123456

search 2 = select * from table where shopname ='abz' and product_id = 123456
```

second search has shopname index

which one will be faster ?

If I understand how indexes work the second one is faster

since it will only search for ids that has shopname ='abz' and ignore other recoreds

Is this correct or I missing something

Comment: Always try avoid to query on a column table that is not indexed. So index `product_id` too

Comment: @juergen d  as far as I know having much indexes will slow down the insertion and deletion .  So do you suggest to make 2 of them indexed ? will it effect the insertion since i'm inserting too much data to this table daily or one of the columns id enough ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your two queries, the optimal index is `table(product_id, shopname)`.  This index can be used by both `where` clauses fully.

If the only index you have is on `shopname`, then the second query should be faster under most circumstances.  That is, `product_id` is not in an index and it is not part of the primary key.

If you have very few shopnames and the table does not fit into memory, then you can end up in a situation called *thrashing*.  However, apart from that circumstance, the index on only `shopname` should be faster, but the above mentioned index is the one you seem to really want.

Comment: In my case shopname will be duplicated  many time  from  100 to unlimited times since each shop can have many products, but for product_id  its unique  for all shops  do you suggest to go with multi columns index   table(product_id, shopname) as you mentioned ?

Comment: @JoumanaIssa . . . Yes, you should go with the multi-column index if these are the queries that you want to run.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience this is what i saw practically in RDBS SELECT SQLs:

When I select data from table with no indexed column value mentioned, it usually takes a lot of time to complete the run and sometimes may result in performance issue.

However when I included an indexed column say customer number with the complete range it magically works out faster!

So, my answer would be to use SQL.2 since it is faster.

SQL.1) The sql engine has no idea where to start on so it does a tablespace scan.

SQL.2) The sql engine has something to start on and it does a indexed scan which is faster in practicality.

However may not be true in all cases it depends on how your data is designed... there may be a case where a SQL.1 works faster since the tablespace scan had the record in the first page itself whereas indexed scan had to reach out till the shop and then get product. Anyway for a overall efficient solution better to go with SQL.2.

Hope it helps :)